# Rails link_to setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I combine

```
<%= link_to do %><li id="message-icon"></li><% end %>
```

and

```
<%= link_to 'My Conversations', :conversations %>
```

I need to use `<li id="message-icon"></li>` instead of the text 'My Conversations'.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you expect but try:

```
<%= link_to :conversations do %><li id="message-icon"></li><% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<%= link_to "<li id='message-icon'></li>".html_safe, :conversations %>
```

Look the generated HTML

```
<a href="/conversations">
    <li id="message-icon"></li>
</a>
```

You can use direct path variable instead of `:conversations` like `conversations_path` with params or without params if you want, you can see all path variables using `rake routes` or `rails routes`.

Or you can use `content_tag` with a block like

```
<%= link_to :conversations do %>
    <%= content_tag :li, "", id: "message-icon" %>
<% end %>
```

it will generate the same HTML which generated above.

You can find some options for `link_to` in [**`UrlHelper`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) API doc.